# Jquery file upload fail

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I found some code to make a jquery upload. It almost works except I don't have any value in the $_FILES variable on the php file that handle the upload. Here's the snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#formsubmit").click(function () {

        var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

        $("body").append(iframe);

        var form = $('#theuploadform');
        form.attr("action", "/upload.aspx");
        form.attr("method", "post");
        form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("target", "postiframe");
        form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
        form.submit();

        $("#postiframe").load(function () {
            iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
        });

        return false;

    });

});

</script>

<form id="theuploadform">
    <input id="userfile" name="userfile" size="50" type="file" />
    <input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<div id="textarea">
</div>
```

Does anyone know what's going on ?

Comment: Forms don't have file attributes. You have to add a file input to the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a header sent problem !
to send file upload to server, you should to use FormData class in javascript/jQuery !
I suggest use this jquery plugin to make it easy :

[jQuery ajax form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)